# Include_once() and absolute path to a file

Tags: php, include

I have the following files:

```
/Index.php
/someFolder/somefile.php
/someFolder/DataBase.php
/config/config.xml
```

In `Index.php` I have included `DataBase.php`:

```
include_once('someFolder/DataBase.php');
```

In `somefile.php` I have included `DataBase.php`:

```
include_once('DataBase.php');
```

Now I want to open `config.xml` from `DataBase.php`:

```
simplexml_load_file('config/config.xml');
```

If I access `config.xml` from `DataBase.php`, which I included in `Index.php` it works, but If I do it from `DataBase.php`, which I included in `somefile.php` I have an error:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity
```

How to deal with it ?

Comment: you can alway check your current directory with `getcwd()` function. dump it where the error is, and check, is that a good path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// resources.inc.php

define('RESOURCE_DIRECTORY', __DIR__.'/resources');

function get_resource($path)
{
    return sprintf('%s/%s', RESOURCE_DIRECTORY, ltrim($path, '/'));
}
```

In procedural projects people normally create a basic configuration file which normalizes the paths to variables or constants.

Using the above example, you should be able to safely acquire the resource using:

```
simplexml_load_file(get_resource('config/config.xml'));
```

You can debate the elegance of this exact solution, but the principle remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

try with -

```
simplexml_load_file('../config/config.xml');
```

Comment: If I do, I can access config.xml from DataBase.php, which I included in somefile.php, but can not access it from DataBase.php, which I included in Index.php.